# Collapsing of factors

Tags: r, forcats

Collapsing of factor levels with forcats::fct_collapse leads to unexpected result

It follows some modified code from the example of fct_collapse

```
require(forcats)
partyid2 <- fct_collapse(gss_cat$partyid,
                         missing = c("No answer"),
                         other = "Other party",
                         rep = c("Strong republican", "Not str republican"),
                         ind = c("Ind,near rep", "Independent", "Ind,near dem"),
                         dem = c("Not str democrat", "Strong democrat"),
                         group_other = TRUE
)
table(gss_cat$partyid, partyid2)
```

Why, for example, does the level 'Strong democrat' end up in the level 'Other' ?

Thank you very much for a hint, what I'm doing wrong.

```
partyid2
                     missing other  rep  ind  dem Other
  No answer              154     0    0    0    0     0
  Don't know               0     1    0    0    0     0
  Other party              0     0  393    0    0     0
  Strong republican        0     0 2314    0    0     0
  Not str republican       0     0    0 3032    0     0
  Ind,near rep             0     0    0 1791    0     0
  Independent              0     0    0 4119    0     0
  Ind,near dem             0     0    0    0 2499     0
  Not str democrat         0     0    0    0 3690     0
  Strong democrat          0     0    0    0    0  3490
```

Comment: Please check if you have `leading/lagging` spacess. try `fct_collapse(trimws(gss_cat$partyid),`

Comment: `trimws()` removes the factor class and results in a different ordering when again recoded as factor. The mismatch of the example goes away but new ones are created.

Comment: Okay then you have to check the exact levels `levels(gss_cat$partyid)` and specify those values. in the `fct_collapse`

Comment: all provided `levels`on the right-hand-side of the named character vector are actual factor levels of `levels(gss_cat$partyid)`.

Comment: I saw an [issue reported on GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats/issues/172) that has been marked a bug that appears to be the same problem you are seeing.

Comment: Okay, thank you, makes sense. Hard to detect when the function is used within mutate and no cross tabulation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the example is not correct.  It changes the order.  TO keep it in the same order

```
partyid2 <- fct_collapse(levels(gss_cat$partyid),
                         missing = c("No answer"),
                          other = "Other party",
                          rep = c("Strong republican", "Not str republican"),
                          ind = c("Ind,near rep", "Independent", "Ind,near dem"),
                          dem = c("Not str democrat", "Strong democrat"),
                          group_other = TRUE
 )[gss_cat$partyid] 
table(gss_cat$partyid, partyid2)
#              partyid2
#                     missing other  rep  ind  dem Other
#  No answer                0     0    0  154    0     0
#  Don't know               1     0    0    0    0     0
#  Other party              0     0    0    0  393     0
#  Strong republican        0     0    0    0    0  2314
#  Not str republican       0     0    0 3032    0     0
#  Ind,near rep             0     0 1791    0    0     0
#  Independent              0     0 4119    0    0     0
#  Ind,near dem             0  2499    0    0    0     0
#  Not str democrat         0     0    0 3690    0     0
#  Strong democrat          0     0    0    0 3490     0
```

Comment: Actually it's the code of `fct_collapse` which changes the order inappropriately, not the example.

Comment: @Andi. Anyway, this works.  I assume that. you want to make it work right/

Comment: Sure, thanks again! But at some point in time (within mutate and with grouped stuff...) I will forget to reorder and carry along the flaws.